# Change Default Font Size in Power BI?

Tags: font-size, powerbi

New Power BI user here- I cannot sort out how to change the default font sizes on my visualizations...

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There's no global default for font size right now. Each visual has its own options for font size.

---

Just in case you're not sure how to change the font size on a visual at all (I suspect you do but want to be thorough), select the visual and then:

1. Choose the **Format** tab of the visual
2. Choose which aspect you want to update (title, legend, and axis are common options for example)
3. Choose the font size

[image: Arrows showing where each step is]

If a visual doesn't have an option for changing a particular font size, you're out of luck. For a custom visual, I'd recommend contacting the author of the visual.

---

If you'd like a global default font size in the future, there are a few ideas you can vote on that will let Microsoft know. Microsoft do pay attention and prioritize work based on who's voting for what, so I do recommend doing this:

**Default Global Font Size**: https://ideas.powerbi.com/forums/265200-power-bi-ideas/suggestions/13470411-default-global-font-size

**Set default visualization formats**: https://ideas.powerbi.com/forums/265200-power-bi-ideas/suggestions/17672380-set-default-visualization-formats

Comment: Thank you for the information Leonard! It was super helpful :)

Answer (score 0):

Use the <kbd>Cntrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>+</kbd>/<kbd>-</kbd> keys to increase or decrease view.

Comment: What exactly you should highlight to perform the action you write about?